# SQL select com duas ou mais ocorrencias de uma tabela na mesma linha?

Tags: mysql

Em um banco relacional rescisões tem **1** contrato, o contrato tem **1** imóvel e duas pessoas(*locador* e *locatário*) como preparo o `SELECT` para retornar estas duas pessoas na mesma linha?

```
SELECT rescisoes.rescisao_id as id,
   rescisoes.data_desocupaçao as desocupação,
   contratos.controle as controle,
   imoveis.logradouro as endereço,
   pessoas.nome as locador, 
   pessoas.nome as locatário 
FROM rescisoes 
  LEFT JOIN contratos ON contratos.contrato_id = rescisoes.contrato_id 
  LEFT JOIN imoveis ON imoveis.imovel_id = contratos.imovel_id 
  LEFT JOIN pessoas ON contratos.locador_pessoa_id = pessoas.pessoa_id
                  OR contratos.locatario_pessoa_id = pessoas.pessoa_id
```

desta forma retorna duas linhas cada uma com locador e locatário com o mesmo nome.

Comment: Instancie a tabela "pessoas" duas vezss uma para o locatário e outra para o locador , serão dois joins , dê aliases diferentes.

Comment: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/557015-select-com-auto-relacionamento-de-n-n/?do=findComment&comment=2222123

Comment: já pensei nisto, contudo da o seguinte erro: #1066 - Tabela/alias 'pessoas' não única a não ser que tenha que fazer mais algum detalhe para funcionar   
LEFT JOIN pessoas ON contratos.locador_pessoa_id = pessoas.pessoa_id
LEFT JOIN pessoas ON contratos.locatario_pessoa_id = pessoas.pessoa_id

Comment: LEFT JOIN pessoas locatario ON contratos.locatario_pessoa_id = locatario .pessoa_id LEFT JOIN pessoas locador ON contratos.locador_pessoa_id = locador.pessoa_id usando os aliases locatario e locador para nomear as colunas

Comment: Valeu cara é isso ai! se puder responder a pergunta com este comentário acima para eu marcar como resposta final eu agradeço!

Comment: SELECT rescisoes.rescisao_id as id, rescisoes.data_desocupaçao as desocupação, contratos.controle as controle, imoveis.logradouro as endereço, locador.nome as locador, locatario.nome as locatário FROM rescisoes LEFT JOIN contratos ON contratos.contrato_id = rescisoes.contrato_id LEFT JOIN imoveis ON imoveis.imovel_id = contratos.imovel_id LEFT JOIN pessoas locador ON contratos.locador_pessoa_id = locador.pessoa_id LEFT JOIN pessoas locatario ON contratos.locatario_pessoa_id = locatario.pessoa_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT rescisoes.rescisao_id as id,
   rescisoes.data_desocupaçao as desocupação,
   contratos.controle as controle,
   imoveis.logradouro as endereço,
   locador.nome as locador, 
   locatario.nome as locatário 
FROM rescisoes 
  LEFT JOIN contratos ON contratos.contrato_id = rescisoes.contrato_id 
  LEFT JOIN imoveis ON imoveis.imovel_id = contratos.imovel_id 
  LEFT JOIN pessoas locador ON contratos.locador_pessoa_id = locador.pessoa_id
    LEFT JOIN pessoas locatario ON contratos.locatario_pessoa_id = locatario.pessoa_id
```